# What is best way for saving access on website with Node.JS

Tags: sql, node.js, query-optimization, nosql

I would save the info of visitors on my website and I would know the best way for make it.

These are info about visitors:

IP, User-Agent, Page Visited, TimeStamp

The operation who I could make are :

```
Write a new guest
Read All Guest
Order by TimeStamp
Group By Page Visited and count
Count for timestamp interval`
```

If I'll use a simple file on disk without DB?
Also NoSql DB could be used, because I have a VPS!

Comment: Guy, edit your post, it's not understandable.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I have edited post!

Comment: So, is your question to store this information in `.txt` or `MongoDB`? If so, either works as long as the client can't access the .txt file.